# using bootstrap 3 audio player but it shows normal html5 output

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, audio, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 player to output audio player but the page shows me normal black html5 audio player output.

Here is my directory structure:

```
miuse/application  
miuse/bootstrap
miuse/bootstrap/css  
miuse/bootstrap/js  
miuse/bootstrap3_player-master  
miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/css  
miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/js
miuse/music
```

Here is my View code(using code-igniter):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
try
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/js/bootstrap3_player.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/css/bootstrap3_player.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=row>
<audio controls>
<source src="http://localhost/miuse/music/eyeofthetiger.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
</audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut this:

```
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/js/bootstrap3_player.js"></script>
```

and paste it in the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
try
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/css/bootstrap3_player.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=row>
<audio controls>
<source src="http://localhost/miuse/music/eyeofthetiger.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
</audio>
</div>
<script src="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap3_player-master/js/bootstrap3_player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```